# is it possible to remove powered by google logo in google address autocomplete api

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

is it possible to remove powered by google logo in google address autocomplete api. I want to remove powered by google logo in my website. I want to show only suggested address in dropdown list. Is it possible to do this or I need to get some paid service for this. Please let me know if there is any optin available to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend that you do not remove it. As per 3.2.2 Requirements for Using the Services. (b) Attribution.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution. So this is what the Terms say, I'd suggest you ask legal advise or ask this question to another platform since we are not lawyers. :'>